# Where clause with one column and multiple criteria returning one row instead of13

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query with a few rows and multiple criteria in the where clause but it is only returning one row instead of 13. No joins and the syntax was triple checked and appears to be free of errors.

Query:

```
select column1, column2, column3
from mydb
where onecolumn in (number1, number2....number13)
```

Results:
returns one row of data associated with a random number in the where clause

spent a big part of the day trying to figure this one out and am now out of ideas. Please help...

Comment: Can you show us your real SQL statement and the data from your table? Also, is onecolumn defined as a char, varchar, integer, other? Obviously, you have a mistake with either your table structure, typing, or SQL statement, but without giving us the details it is next to impossible to help.

Comment: Try setting up a SQL Fiddle.  The obvious conclusion is that only one of the numbers is in your data.

Comment: Did u spend a part of that day looking at data or just the code

Comment: the obvious thing you can try is to test each value in the "in" clause, like this -- select column1, column2, column3 from mydb where onecolumn in (number1), then select column1, column2, column3 from mydb where onecolumn in (number2), until you test all values

Comment: @Leo that is as insane as the op question

Answer (score 1):

Absent a more detailed test case, and the actual SQL statement that is actually running, this question cannot be answered. Here are some "ideas"...

---

Our first guess is that the rows you think are going to satisfy the predicates aren't actually satisfying *all* of the conditions.

---

Our second guess is that you've got an aggregate expression (`COUNT()`, `MAX()`, `SUM()`) in the SELECT list that's causing an implicit `GROUP BY`. This is a common "gotcha"... the non-standard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY` which allows non-aggregates to appear in the SELECT list, which are not also included as expressions in the GROUP BY clause.  This same gotcha appears when the `GROUP BY` clause is omitted entirely, and an aggregate is included in the `SELECT` list.

But the question doesn't make any mention of an aggregate expression in the SELECT list.

---

Our third guess is another issue that beginners frequently overlook: the *order of precedence* of operations, especially `AND` and `OR`. For example, consider the expressions:

```
  a AND b OR c
  a AND ( b OR c )
  ( a AND b ) OR c
```

consider those while we sing-along, Sesame Street style,...: "One of these things is not like the others, one of these things just doesn't belong..."

---

A fourth guess... if it wasn't for the row being returned having a value of `onecolumn` as a *random* number in the `IN` list... if it was instead the *first* number in the `IN` list, we'd be very suspicious that the IN list actually contains a *single* string value that *looks like* a list a values, but is actually not.

The two expression in the SELECT list look very similar, but they are very different:

```
  SELECT t.n IN (2,3,5,7)   AS n_in_list 
       , t.n IN ('2,3,5,7') AS n_in_string 
    FROM ( SELECT 2 AS n
           UNION ALL SELECT 3
           UNION ALL SELECT 5
         ) t
```

The first expression is comparing `n` to each value in a list of four values.
The second expression is equivalent to `t.n IN (2)`.

This is a frequent trip up when neophytes are dynamically creating SQL text, thinking that they can pass in a string value and that MySQL will see the *commas* within the string as part of the SQL statement.

(But this doesn't explain how a some the *random* one in the list.)

---

Those are all just guesses. Those are some of the most frequent trip ups we see, but we're just guessing. It could be something else entirely. In it's current form, there is no definitive "answer" to the question.

Comment: Hmmm . . . You left out the possibility that `mydb` is a view that uses `rand()` for filtering ;)

Comment: @GordonLinoff: (In the best Yoda impersonation I can muster:  "Wise beyond your years and correct you are." I also omitted the possibility of a LIMIT clause appended to the end of the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff:  we also left out the possibility that the client is fetching only one row, or looping through the rows fetched and assigning values to the same scalar. But I've got my money on the second guess in my answer... i.e. an aggregate expression in the SELECT list and no GROUP BY clause. That would explain the observed behavior: "only one row" as well as the returned row having some "random" value from the IN list. If it was some other number of rows being returned (zero or more than one), then that guess moves so far down the list, it almost falls off the list.

Comment: spencer7593, thanks for putting the time in with all your answers, it is very much appreciated!  the solution was guess#2, I added a group by and it worked